# .htaccess cache-control doesn't cache my files (js|png|css etc.)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, cache-control

As my title says, I am trying to cache-control the content on my website but it seems that my content isn't being cached.

This is my code in my .htaccess file:

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

# cache images/pdf docs for 10 days
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000, public, must-revalidate"
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>

# cache html/htm/xml/txt diles for 2 hours
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

I have tried a lot of tutorials but none of them seems to do the trick.
By the way, other .htaccess codes, like redirecting and stuff, DOES work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured it out, you gotta remove `Header unset Last-Modified`

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

# cache images/pdf docs for 10 days
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# cache html/htm/xml/txt files for 2 hours
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Upvote for solving your own problem, and posting back solution.